# Precise difference between statement on Row and on Table

Tags: oracle, plsql

What's the difference between these two blocks and when to use the first or the second?

```
Create OR Replace trigger trig_before_insert before insert on Employee For each Row 
Begin 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting');
END;
```

And

```
Create OR Replace trigger trig_before_insert before insert on Employee
Begin 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting');
END;
```

Comment: [There you go](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i2013)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you perform an

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
SELECT ...
```

and that `SELECT` returns 100 rows so that the `INSERT` inserts 100 rows, your first trigger will execute 100 times, once for each row.  In the same situation, your second trigger will execute only once.

You can use a `BEFORE INSERT...FOR EACH ROW` trigger to change the values that are being inserted by accessing them via the `:NEW` variable.  E.g.,

```
:new.column_1 := 'a different value';
```

You cannot do that in a statement level trigger (which is what your 2nd trigger is).

There are also limitations in row level triggers (which is what your 1st trigger is).  In particular, you may not `SELECT` from the trigger's base table (`EMPLOYEES` in this case), because that table is said to be "mutating".  The exact reasons, as I understand them, go back to the core principles of relational databases -- specifically that the results of a statement (like `INSERT INTO...SELECT`) should not depend on the order in which the rows are processed.  There are workarounds to this limitation, however, which are beyond the scope of your original question, I think.